# Update values in sql when the data is being printed using while

Tags: php, button, while-loop

The form is used so that the method post could be used whenever the button is clicked, for more info go through the code.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <?php
        //selecting rowa where the approve status is false or simple "0"
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id, rid, time, amount, transid, wallet FROM donations WHERE approve = 0");
        //this button will be used later update the rows and set approve to true or "1"
        $button = "<button type='submit' name='approve' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>" . "APPROVE" . "</button>";
        echo "<table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>RID</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th>AMOUNT</th>
                <th>TRANS HASH</th>
                <th>WALLET</th>
                <th>APPROVE</th>
            </tr>";
        //printing all the values where approve = '0'
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $row['rid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-2'>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-3'>" . $row['transid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-3'>" . $row['wallet'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $button . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }echo "</table>";
        //when the button is clicked, the method 'post' is invoked and the value is updated
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $approve = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `donations` SET approve = 1 WHERE approve = 0 and id = '$id'");
        }
    ?>
```

The problem here is that I want a button for each row and each should be updated individually when that row's button is clicked.

Comment: Then you are going to have to either use javascript to AJAX the data to PHP or change your button into an anchor tag with a querystring containing a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** Change your code order . update part should be in page top.Because you need to update if it's submit .then only you need to fetch data from database . In your order your fetching the data and showing to user then updating at last . it should not be like this.

**2nd :** Just pass the `row id` as `submit` button `value` like this and it should be inside the while loop .

```
$button = "<button type='submit' name='approve' value='".$row["id"]."' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>" . "APPROVE" . "</button>";
```

**3rd :** On submit you will get the row id in `$_POST['approve']`

```
<?php
     if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            $id = $_POST['approve'];
            $approve = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `donations` SET approve = 1 WHERE approve = 0 and id =$id");
        }
?>
```

Note : The above code should be on page top .

**Update 1** : The code order should be like this

```
<?php

        //when the button is clicked, the method 'post' is invoked and the value is updated
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            $id = $_POST['approve'];
            $approve = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `donations` SET approve = 1 WHERE approve = 0 and id =$id");
        }
?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <?php

        //selecting rowa where the approve status is false or simple "0"
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id, rid, time, amount, transid, wallet FROM donations WHERE approve = 0");
        //this button will be used later update the rows and set approve to true or "1"

        echo "<table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>RID</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th>AMOUNT</th>
                <th>TRANS HASH</th>
                <th>WALLET</th>
                <th>APPROVE</th>
            </tr>";
        //printing all the values where approve = '0'
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $button = "<button type='submit' name='approve' value='".$row["id"]."' class='btn btn-success' role='button'>" . "APPROVE" . "</button>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $row['rid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-2'>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-3'>" . $row['transid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-3'>" . $row['wallet'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td class='col-sm-1'>" . $button . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

**Update 2** : Try to use `prepared statement` to avoid `sql injection`

Comment: what do you mean by "prepared statement" ?

Comment: still not getting anything, shows an error message when I load the page. "Undefined index: id". The error is at button line where we are assigning $row['id'] to the button.

Comment: after putting the $button inside the while loop and changing the apostrophe, it worked fine. Thank You @JYoThI

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick .it's useful for future user reference @RaviGohel

Comment: I did, I have one more question to ask, what do I do if I want to update more than 1 value?

Comment: if you want update more than one value means . just follow the riggsFolly comment .